# Pass [Object object] to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi I have a button that passes `this` to a function as below:

```
<div class="itemRow">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteMessage(this, 3);" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
</div>
```

For the sake of keeping this simple, I have removed other elements within the `itemRow` div. Essentially this div contains information about an item as well as a button to delete that item. Every item will have a `itemRow` div so there are many on the page. I want to determine which row the button call came from so that when the item is actually deleted, the correct row is removed.

```
function deleteMessage(row, itemNum){
$('#deleteMsgModal').modal('show');
//Change the modal buttons's onclick handler
$("#deleteConfirmBtn").click(function(){ deleteRow(row, itemNum);});
}
```

So the above function will display a modal that asks for confirmation. The onclick handler of the button in the modal takes in the `this` object and the item number which then goes to a seperate function `deleteRow` that actually deletes the row and removes the row.

```
function deleteRow(contentRow, itemNo){
var item = itemNo;
//do some ajax code to remove the row from the database...
...
//then once it is removed then to remove the div that is showing the row...
$(contentRow).parent().remove();
}
```

The problem is that when the `#deleteConfirmBtn` button's click handler takes in `this` as an argument, it displays it as `[Object object]` which will not work. Is there a way I can get around this so that the final function can delete the correct div?

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap 'this' in $ sign. so in your case would be $(row)

Comment: When I do that, the onclick handler looks like the following:
onclick="deleteRow($(javascript:void(0);),3). That returns the following error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: never mind, I see you already doing it $(contentRow).parent().remove(); where did you console.log?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, 
"The problem is that when the #deleteConfirmBtn button's click handler takes in this as an argument, it displays it as [Object object] which will not work."
Where is the html for this and how are you passing in **'this'** value to this function.

My concern, Why is it required to pass **this**, when you are already binding click event to the button. **this** value should be already passed along in the function.

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

You may use the event handling that comes with jQuery. If you register the click handlers in Javascript, you don't need to pass `this` to the function. jQuery gives you that reference automatically.

I have done several changes to your code to make a running example without using bootstrap:

1. Each delete button now haves a data property `data-row="x"` where `x` is the number of the row. I have also added a tag class to retrieve all these buttons: `.btn-delete`.
2. As you can see, the click handler is registered on Javascript. Once you click a delete button, the row number is retrieved from the previously set data porperty.
3. Each time you process a *Confirm delete* event, you need to unbind the click handler. If you don't do it, you may end with unexpected behaviours where the previous delete actions are triggered again.

```js
// Event delegated subscription for all the delete events
$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function(event) {
  // Prevent navigation event of the anchor
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get the info of the clicked event
  let rowElement = $(this);
  let rowNumber = rowElement.data('row');
  // Show the confirmation message
  $('#deleteMsgModal').show();
  //Change the modal buttons's onclick handler
  $("#deleteConfirmBtn").click( function(ev) {
    // Prevent event propagation
    ev.preventDefault();
    // Remove the 'modal' message and unbind this click event handler
    $('#deleteMsgModal').hide()
    $(this).unbind('click');
    deleteRow(rowElement, rowNumber);
  });
});

function deleteRow(contentRow, itemNo){
  let item = itemNo;
  alert('Item #' + itemNo + ' removed succesfully');
  // do some ajax code to remove the row from the database...
  // ...
  // then once it is removed then to remove the div that is showing the row...
  contentRow.parent().remove();
}
```

```css
#deleteMsgModal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemRow">
  <span>Row 1</span>
  <a href="#" data-row="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete">Delete</a>
</div>
<div class="itemRow">
  <span>Row 2</span>
  <a href="#" data-row="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete">Delete</a>
</div>
<div class="itemRow">
  <span>Row 3</span>
  <a href="#" data-row="3" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete">Delete</a>
</div>
<div id="deleteMsgModal">
  You are about to delete a row. Are you sure?
  <a href="#" id="deleteConfirmBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm delete</a>
<div>
```